# Deleting tables with mysqli_multi_query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I'm trying to delete my principle table 'eleve', with deleting others table which has their primary key in this one. I tried like in the attached code, but I got an error:

> (Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 'from bource where ID_BOURCE = 1delete from class where ID_CLASS = 1delete from p' � la ligne 1)

Any ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['butAj4'])) {
  $queryDel = "delete from inscription where NUM_INSCRIPTION = $NUM_INSCRIPTION";
  $queryDel. = "delete from bource where ID_BOURCE = $ID_BOURCE";
  $queryDel. = "delete from class where ID_CLASS = $ID_CLASS";
  $queryDel. = "delete from project where ID_PROJECT = $ID_PROJECT";
  $queryDel. = "delete from annee_scolaire where ID_ANNEE = $ID_ANNEE";
  $queryDel. = "delete from eleve where CIN_ELEVE = '$InputCIN'";

  if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $queryDel)) {
    $msg3 = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Bien suppression</div>";
  } else {
    $msg3 = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>error dans la suppression</div>".mysqli_error($con);

  }
}
```

Comment: dont use multi query, its almost always a bad idea

Comment: @rtfm ok man i will make single query for each table

Comment: That should work you're just forgetting the `;` at the end of each query. For example: `"delete from eleve where CIN_ELEVE = '$InputCIN';"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do it like this there are better ways but to answer your question do it like this:

```
$queryDel = "
delete from inscription where NUM_INSCRIPTION= $NUM_INSCRIPTION ;
delete from bource where ID_BOURCE = $ID_BOURCE ;
delete from class where ID_CLASS = $ID_CLASS ;
delete from project where ID_PROJECT = $ID_PROJECT ;
delete from annee_scolaire where ID_ANNEE = $ID_ANNEE ;
delete from eleve where CIN_ELEVE = '$InputCIN'; ";

$result=mysqli_multi_query($con,$queryDel);
```

and also remember to clear the results else you wont be able to perform another query but i don't think delete will return a result.

```
while(mysqli_next_result($con)){;} //clear any remaining query results.
```

also remember that if one query fails all the rest will not run. so to debug try running each query separately first and make sure it all works since its a delete statement back up your database before running the query and restore as when needed.

Comment: thanks man its working well now,can you suggest a better way to do it ?

Comment: i will suggest using PDO or if your not too good with classes just make sure you implement mysqli_stmt_bind_param(); see:  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  A delete statement can be deadly if injected so take all necessary steps to protect your database

Comment: i really appreciate that,i will check about it

Comment: @medo100000S multi-query is dangerous.  Multi-query with string interpolation is fundamentally and critically flawed.  If a malicious user could find a way to set the value of `$NUM_INSCRIPTION` to a string such as `0; DROP TABLE inscription;` then you should be able to see what could go terribly, terribly wrong here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are right man,i used to exploit single query in each request