# Delete from multiple tables in a single SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

would like to seek your help for deleting rows from multiple tables.

Columns of Table A)
indexnum people title

Columns of Table B)
indexnum jobtitle status

what I would like to do is delete any rows from two tables, that has a certain index number, which would be accomplished by,

```
DELETE A WHERE num='1';
DELETE B WHERE num='1';
```

Can I do this in a single SQL?

I have looked up in other Q&As with recommendations to use INNER JOIN but wasn't able to make up one for my own...

Comment: Is there any foreign key correlation between the two tables?

Comment: Why don't you create a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The generic answer is "cascading delete triggers".

Comment: 1. There aren't any correlation set between these tables
2. Main reason for doing this is because I am using a dataset as an underlying source for a Grid control in C#, and the displayed grid retrieves data from multiple tables. and I need to delete a certain row, not knowing the row originated from, by clicking the "delete" button which calls SqlAdapter.Update command.

Comment: see previous/similar answer on deleting multi tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604399/deleting-tables-with-mysqli-multi-query/48604488#48604488

and please keep to the warnings on the answer.